# how to do forest float from data i have

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I have results of 4 models on 8 variables that I wanted to insert into the forest plot in a nice and clear way.
I tried to execute but all I found was forest plot that the system calculates
I would appreciate help on how to do this

the data
or model 1  CI model 1  CI model 1  or model 2  ci model 2  ci model 2  or model 3  ci model 3  ci model 3  or model 4  ci model 4  ci model 4
models  0.84    0.83    0.86    0.83    0.82    0.85    1.08    1   1.17    1.22    1.09    1.35
a   1.17    1.14    1.21    1.11    1.08    1.15    1.6 1.39    1.83    1.62    1.35    1.94
b   1.15    1.12    1.18    1.09    1.06    1.12    1.43    1.27    1.62    1.47    1.25    1.73
c   1.16    1.13    1.2 1.1 1.07    1.13    1.55    1.36    1.76    1.58    1.33    1.88
d   0.97    0.94    0.99    0.92    0.9 0.94    1.31    1.17    1.46    1.42    1.23    1.64
e   0.87    0.85    0.88    0.83    0.82    0.85    1.13    1.04    1.24    1.35    1.2 1.51
f   0.87    0.85    0.89    0.86    0.85    0.88    1.07    0.97    1.17    1.23    1.09    1.39
g   0.82    0.81    0.84    0.79    0.77    0.81    1.05    0.96    1.16    1.12    0.98    1.27

this is that I  expecting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A98Zq.png)

Comment: Please can you share some code that you've tried, as part of a reproducible example? Ideally share your data using `dput()` as well. Please don't share data or code as images - insert them into your question using code blocks instead as it makes it easier for others to help you.